# Using useEffect like ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to have 3 buttons where if one is in an active state, the other 2 will automatically be inactive.

```
 if (isActive === "true") {
            setActive2("false")
            setActive3("false")
          }
          if (isActive2 === "true") {
            setActive("false")
            setActive3("false")
          }
          if (isActive3 === "true") {
            setActive("false")
            setActive2("false")
          }
```

I'm aware there's probably a better way of doing this and this is a brute force option, and I'm open to your suggestions.

I have tried putting this block of code in a function and running it whenever the buttons are clicked, but that is giving me the previous state instead of the current state.
So I was suggested to use the `useEffect` hook.

```
 useEffect(() => {
          
          if (isActive === "true") {
            setActive2("false")
            setActive3("false")
          }
          if (isActive2 === "true") {
            setActive("false")
            setActive3("false")
          }
          if (isActive3 === "true") {
            setActive("false")
            setActive2("false")
          }
}, [isActive, isActive2, isActive3]);
```

However this is giving me the same issue, where the previous state is being applied.

 I am for sure doing something very wrong with this hook (i have never used it before).
I have a codesandbox with all my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-frog-vb8u0?file=/src/CYO.js)

Comment: I really disagree using `useEffect` for this. You can simply call a function, like `handleButtonClick` and do what you want. Another point, are you using `true` really as string? `"true"` is different from `true`, maybe this can help you.

Comment: I changed the true from "true" that was truly my bad. 
But I have tried to use it in a function. I had my function ```ButtonStuff()``` being called everytime the user presses the buttons. But it would update with the previous state

Comment: Just have one button state called `activeButton` which you set to a value 1, 2 or 3. Then use that in your component as a prop. E.g. in button 1 have `active={activeButton === 1}`. Then on click, you can set activeButton to 1 if it isn't already, otherwise set it to null. This will be much simpler and safer.

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp : Hi there! Have provided a solution for your checkbox selection problem. Do vote and accept the answer if it helps :) Thanks You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have modified only the `onChange handler` in an efficient way without touching `JSX` much and have worked on your set-up only. CodeSandBox Link [Checkbox-Selection](https://codesandbox.io/s/the-checkbox-issue-21v4b)

**Some Major changes that I did are as follows:**

1. Instead of setting seperate state to each button, I have used a single object with 3 keys `isActive`, `isActive2` and `isActive3`.

   ```
   const [btnStatus, setBtnStatus] = useState({
    isActive: true,
     isActive2: true,
     isActive3: true
   });
   ```
2. Your Handler looks something like this now.

   ```
   const addPizza = (e) => {
    setPizzaSize(e.target.name);
    setStartPrice(parseInt(e.target.value));
   const currentActive = e.target.id;

   if (currentActive === "isActive") {
     setBtnStatus({ isActive: true, isActive2: false, isActive3: false });
     console.log("1");
   }
   if (currentActive === "isActive2") {
     setBtnStatus({ isActive: false, isActive2: true, isActive3: false });
     console.log("2");
   }
   if (currentActive === "isActive3") {
     setBtnStatus({ isActive: false, isActive2: false, isActive3: true });
     console.log("3");
   }

   console.log(btnStatus);
   };
   ```
3. In your JSX each button will look like this, with own `ids` to track the status of button.

   ```
     <button
       name="Extra Large"
       className={
         btnStatus.isActive3
           ? "button btn fourth"
           : "button btn fourthActive"
       }
       value="20"
       onClick={addPizza}
       id="isActive3"
     >
       Extra large
     </button>
   ```

And here you go. All working nicely with the same code :)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have update the code a little bit, you can create seprate constants and use them to reduce the code and also, to keep the active state use a single state only.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-franklin-m8wkx?file=/src/CYO.js:0-4147

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ButtonClickable from "./button";
import ButtonClickable2 from "./button2";
import { burgerSize, vegToppings, nonvegToppings } from "./const/size";
import "./index.css";

const CYO = () => {
  const [pizzaSize, setPizzaSize] = useState("Choose your Pizza Size");
  const [activeSize, setActiveSize] = useState(burgerSize.MEDIUM);
  const [toppings, setToppings] = useState([]);
  const [startPrice, setStartPrice] = useState(0);
  const addPizza = (e) => {
    setPizzaSize(e.target.name);
    setStartPrice(parseInt(e.target.value));
  };

  const CheckSize = () => {
    if (pizzaSize === "Choose your Pizza Size") {
      alert("You must choose a pizza size");
    } else if (toppings.length === 0) {
      alert("Are you sure you don't want toppings?");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, this isn't a real pizza place.");
    }
  };
  const ToppingPlusMinus = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const position = toppings.indexOf(value);

    if (position !== -1) {
      return removeTopping(value);
    }

    return addTopping(value);
  };

  const removeTopping = (value) => {
    // We need to filter out the value from the array and return the expected new value
    setToppings(toppings.filter((topping) => topping !== value));
    //handleToggle();
  };

  const addTopping = (value) => {
    setToppings([...toppings, value]);
    // handleToggle();
  };

  let toppingPrice = toppings.length * 1.5;
  let price = startPrice + toppingPrice;

  return (
    <div className="container CYO">
      <h2 className="text-center white">Create your own pizza</h2>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-8">
          <div className="">
            <img
              src="./pizza.png"
              className="img-fluid pizza"
              alt="Pizza"
            ></img>
          </div>
          <h3 className="white">{pizzaSize}</h3>
          <p className="white">
            Your Toppings: <br />
            <div className="col-lg-12">
              {toppings
                .filter((x) => x.name !== "")
                .map((toppings) => (
                  <img
                    src={toppings}
                    alt="topping"
                    width="100px"
                    height="100px"
                  ></img>
                ))}
            </div>{" "}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-4">
          <h3 className="white">Pizza size</h3>
          {Object.values(burgerSize).map((value) => (
            <button
              name={value}
              className={
                activeSize !== value
                  ? "button btn fourth"
                  : "button btn fourthActive"
              }
              value="10"
              onClick={(event) => {
                addPizza(event);
                setActiveSize(value);
              }}
            >
              {value}
            </button>
          ))}
          <br />
          <h3 className="white">Toppings</h3>
          <p className="white">Toppings are $1.50 each</p>
          <div className="topping-wrapper">
            <h4 className="white">Meats</h4>
            {nonvegToppings.map(({ name, image }) => (
              <ButtonClickable
                onClick={(event) => {
                  ToppingPlusMinus(event);
                }}
                name={name}
                value={image}
              />
            ))}

            <h4 className="white">Veggies</h4>
            {vegToppings.map(({ name, image }) => (
              <ButtonClickable2
                onClick={(event) => {
                  ToppingPlusMinus(event);
                }}
                name={name}
                value={image}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="pricefooter">
          <p className="price">Price: ${price}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="pricefooter2">
          <button className="checkout button btn fourth" onClick={CheckSize}>
            Checkout
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CYO;
```

Comment: You can improve more things on this, i have updated a few things only just to give you some ideas that what can be improved